# Past and present tense in a one sentence

Tags: grammar, tenses

> What we understand as “love” was put into our mind in childhood when we didn’t understand that term. **The way our parents treated us in childhood reflects on our subconscious and understanding of love.**

I am concerned about the second sentence tenses (past and present) and its grammar.

Comment: 'What I went through does not affect me now.' The what-clause uses the past simple; the whole clause is the subject of the sentence 'X does not affect me now'. No problem.

Answer (score 1):

"The way our parents treated us in childhood" is a noun clause and the subject of "reflects".

Compare:

{The way our parents treated us in childhood} reflects on our subconscious and understanding of love.

and

{It} reflects on our subconscious and understanding of love.

As a consequence, the tense of the verb in the noun clause is irrelevant to the main verb "reflects".

Compare:

{The way our **children will treat** us our old age} reflects on our subconscious and understanding of love.

{The way our **friends treat** us now} reflects on our subconscious and understanding of love.

Comment: OP means the second sentence in the body text: the bolded one.